# How to make the subscriptions module produce notifications on a screen?

Tags: 7, notifications

Really struggling with subscriptions on my site or users.

I'm currently trying the [subscriptions](https://www.drupal.org/project/subscriptions) module, but I am unable to have the user notified on the site iself. I can see it can send emails to the users which is good, but I also would like to have a little notification at the top like stackexchange has.

Anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Maybe subscriptions isn't the right tool? Notification module looks like it is struggling to find maintainers.

Comment: Have a look at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/179158 for a potential alternative ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same thing I wanted to do for some kind of notification.
Finally, this was the implementation:

- Added one function which returns the count and notification with HTML.
- Then added Ajax request to fetch the result and place it on the notification element which is already placed in page.tpl.php
- Added JS code to custom.js which works on every page of site.
- See below:

[image]

- But remember don't make it heavy ajax request, it may slow down your site. And remember to add JS code at bottom of page.
- Also you can do one thing, put ajax request on click of the element, look what StackExchage do:

[image]

- on click of notification they send request and fetch the data...